# "Installing fonts on request isn't supported" Error message

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

I received the following error message; not sure what caused it, but it possibly followed opening LibreCalc's Cell Formatting options box, with `Ctrl` + `1`.

> Title: "Installing fonts on request isn't supported"
>   Message: "Currently auto-detection and installation of missing fonts is not
>   supported"

Web showed no results for this error.  Should I go to ask.LibreOffice.org?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a document that was created with Windows and the fonts are not installed. Try installing the MS-Corefonts:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

That should fix your problem.

There are meta-packages for restricted extras, like codecs and fonts. This depends on your desktop-environment. Choose **one** of them.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras   # Gnome based
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-restricted-extras  # KDE
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-restricted-extras  # LXDE
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-restricted-extras  # XFCE
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found a solution:

As I had had those ms-corefonts installed before, they couldn't be the cause of the error message.

I concluded the cause must have been me having deinstalled all Asian fonts; I did not want to reinstall them with those meta-packages.

Here's what I did - and I haven't seen the message since:

In LibreOffice, go to

- -> Tools
- -> Options
- -> Language Settings
- -> Languages

Under "Default Languages for Documents" I had unticked the boxes for "Asian" and "Complex Text Layout" before,

- -> so I ticked them now
- -> both settings hold scrollable lists of languages:
- -> I selected the top entries: [None]

clicked OK & that's it!